# How to automate my testing that connects (and modifys) to an external server

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm currently writing a Java program that is an interface to another server. The majority of the functions (close to >90%) do something on the server. Currently, I'm just writing simple classes that run some actions on the server, and then check it myself, or add methods to the test that read back the written information.

Currently, I'm developing on my own computer, and have a version of the server running locally on a VM.

I don't want to continually run the tests at every build, as I don't want to keep modifying the server I am connected too. I am not sure the best way to go about my testing. I have my JUnit tests (on simple functions that do not interact externally) that run every build. I can't seem to see the set way in JUnit to write tests that do not have to run at every build (perhaps when their functions change?).

Or, can anyone point me in the correct direction of how to best handle my testing.

Thanks!

Comment: How about a test server? even a local one

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to continually run the tests at every build, as I don't want to keep modifying the server I am connected to

This should have raised the alarms for you. Running the tests is what gives you feedback on whether you broke stuff. Not running them means you're blind. It does not mean that everything is fine.

There are several approaches, depending on how much access you have to the server code.

**Full Access**

If you're writing the server yourself, or you have access to the code, then you can create a test-kit for the server - A modified version of the server that runs completely in-memory and allows you to control how the server responds, so you can simulate different scenarios.

This kind of test-kit is created by separating the logic parts of the server from its surroundings, and then mocking them or creating in-memory versions of them (such as databases, queues, file-systems, etc.). This allows the server to run very quickly and it can then be created and destroyed within the test itself.

**Limited/No Access**

If you have to write tests for integration with a server that's out of your control, such as a 3rd party API, then the approach is to write a "mock" of the remote service, and a contract test to check that the mock still behaves the same way as the real thing. I usually put those in a different build, and run that occasionally just to know that my mock server hasn't diverged from the real server.

Once you have your mock server, you can write an adapter layer for it, covered by integration tests. The rest of your code will only use the adapter, and therefore can be tested using plain unit tests.

---

The second approach can, of course, be employed when you have full access as well, but usually writing the test-kit is better, since those kinds of tests tend to be duplicated across projects and teams, and then when the server changes a whole bunch of people need to fix their tests, whereas if the test-kit is written as part of the server code, it only has to be altered in one place.